# How to add a new element after the script that invoke this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that call a script such as :

```
<script src="http://www.mypage.com/widget/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

inside this script I get the current "script" on execution, with :

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var myScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

now, what I'd like to do, is to add after this "element" (I mean, after the script in my calling page) a new one, such as :

```
<div>New Element</div>
```

so the final result in my page will be :

```
<script src="http://www.mypage.com/widget/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>New Element</div>
```

how can I do it? I think I'll wrap `myScript` with jquery, but don't know how to add a new element after this one in the DOM.

Comment: why would you want to add a <div> element after a specific script element??

Comment: Why no? :D because I'm adding a widget...

Comment: The order of elements doesn't matter here. The script would have already been executed before you added the element

Comment: @JasonEvans : ? script it is not in the head...is inside the page!

Comment: @jason That has nothing to do with the html being well-formed. `<script>` tags can appear anywhere, no specific location is given in the html spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var d = $('<div>');
d.text("new element");
$(myScript).after(d);
```

Comment: Can I also do this with pure javascript?

Comment: @markzzz Yes jQuery is written in JavaScript, so anything that can be done with jQuery can be done in 'pure' JS as well. That being said, it won't be nearly as straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/rSRdC/1/ This more or less does it (there are some subtleties with text nodes, but I think it's fine)